# How to create groupbox element click Listner in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, click, groupbox

I have groupbox with 2 element inside it. I want, when I click on one element inside group box then other element should be deselected. I can do it by making separate listener for all element. Like this.

```
private void maleBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (femaleCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                femaleCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private void femleBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (maleCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                maleCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```

But I want a single click listener which handle it.[image]

Comment: Why dont you use radio buttons for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you really would need here are radio-buttons.
Add a groupbox and then your radio-buttons inside of that.

To make the event trigger if any radio-button-state changes, you will have to add the event to each radio-button (as far as I know). You could do that with a foreach loop on `groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()` if you don't want to do it by hand.
**Keep in mind that the event will fire twice (once for switching off of one and then another time for switching on to one).**

If you really do need checkboxes you will still have to add the event for each one and you can still do that with the foreach loop just switch the type of course.

I hope this makes sense to you :)